# Is there a way to make a ClickableSpan background round?

Tags: java, android, clickablespan

Is there a way to make the background of the ClickableSpan class rounded instead of the default rectangle? This is my base custom ClickableSpan class:

```
public class TagSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setColor(ds.linkColor);
        ds.bgColor = Color.GRAY; //Gray rectangle background that would love her corners rounded
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
}
```